# .NET Console App throws error when scheduled. Runs fine when executed manually

Tags: c#, .net, windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

So I decided to make a console application to automate some repetitive jobs that I generally do on a daily basis. The objective is to move some files to a network location as backup. The application runs fine when executed manually. But when scheduled, it throws an error. On examining the log file (to which all program output is mapped), I found the following stack trace and exception message:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at automateDump.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\software\automateDump\Program.cs:line 78
 The user name or password is incorrect.
```

I'm using the `File.Copy(src, dest)` method in `System.IO`.

And for context, the file paths are:

Source: `D:\u01\test.file`. Destination: `\\NetDrive\test.file`

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Code:

```
if (File.Exists(movePath + et1))
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Copying {et1} to network location. Size - {sizeInMegaBytes(new FileInfo(movePath + et1).Length)}");
     File.Copy(movePath + et1, networkPath + et1);
     Console.WriteLine("Done Copying");
}
```

`movePath` and `networkPath` are source and destination paths, and `et1` is the file.

`sizeInMegaBytes()` is a utility function that I wrote. It's irrelevant in this context.

**EDIT 2**

Exception Handling code:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (logger = File.AppendText(@"D:\u01\logs.txt"))
    {
         logger.WriteLine($"{ex.StackTrace} \n {ex.Message}");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please post also the code you're using

Comment: Does your application runs with a user which has necessary permissions to the source and target file locations?

Comment: How are you running this application? It seems to be a permission problem. If you are using windows service or scheduled jobs, you are able to run as... an specific user with the  
corresponding permissions

Comment: @Chetan yes it does. I double checked when scheduling it.

Comment: What is the value of the `Message` property in the exception?

Comment: @Developer90 I'm using windows task scheduler. The account is the same one that I use to carry out the task manually. PS - It works fine when the `.exe` is double clicked. Throws an error when scheduled.

Comment: Which is the user account which runs the scheduled task?

Comment: @Chetan I'm not sure why you need the account, but nonetheless, it's called `oracle` and it is the one which I use to manually carry out the task. And yes, it does have read/write permissions to the network drive.

Comment: From the error message, the access to the uNC path is failing.
Try 1. setting the scheduled task to load the user's profile, 2. using a mapped path.
(The scheduler doesn't load the user fully for scheduled jobs, compared to when loging in interactively.))

Comment: Alternatively ensure the task is saving the user's password 9and lo9ok at the text for that option)

Answer (score 0):

Theory: you have not checked the option to save the user password for the task:

[image]

Note the explanatory text: using a UNC path means you are trying to access a non-local resource!